# Biopython - String assigning error

Tags: python, biopython

I tried to begin with Biopython. So that I can do my thesis in it. But this really makes me think twice. Show features missing, when I tried a integer value, it does not work and same is the case with string too. Kindly help. Thank you.

Link:

http://imgur.com/87Gw9E5

Comment: "it does not work" is a pretty vague error description.

Comment: Your `while` condition is checking that 0 is greater than the length of something. You don't actually show where `features` is defined, but unless it's some awful hacked-together object that somehow returns a negative length, your loop will never run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys at Biopython actually made it easy to deal with the features. Your problem is string management (plain python). I've used `format`, but you can use the `%` operator.

Also in python you rarely have to keep the count when looping. Python is not C.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for record in SeqIO.parse("NG_009616.gb", "genbank"):

    # You don't have to take care of the number of features with a while
    # Loop all of them.
    for feature in record.features:
        print "Attributes of feature"
        print "Type {0}".format(feature.type)
        print "Start {0}".format(feature.location.start)
        print "End {0}".format(feature.location.end)
        print "Qualifiers {0}".format(feature.qualifiers)
        # This is the right way to extract the sequence:
        print "Sequence {0}".format(feature.location.extract(record).seq)
        print "Sub-features {0}".format(feature.sub_features)
```

Answer (score 2):

Biopython seems pretty robust to me, the errors are probably due to your inexperience with it.

You have several errors, one of them is that you forgot to end the strings with "". The following lines

```
print "location start, features[ftNum].location.start # note location.start"
print "feature qualifiers,features[ftNum].qualifiers"
```

should be corrected to

```
print "location start", features[ftNum].location.start # note location.start
print "feature qualifiers", features[ftNum].qualifiers
```

Furthermore, as Wooble pointed out the condition in your while loop is wrong. I'm guessing you meant to  to invert the ">", that is, the number of features should be greater than zero.

Please add some example data and error messages.